# "Cannot save project" when trying to add a project to gitlab-ci

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

As the title states...

I've migrated gitlab to 6.0-stable and also set up gitlab-ci 4.1.0, and a runner. The runner is set up successfully and shows up in the CI interface. I can see all repositories from gitlab, but any click on "add build" in CI returns a warning message "Cannot save project".

The `production.log` of gitlab-ci shows correct POST params, as I can assess.

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-01 19:48:29 +0100
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qu1GFc8FwyGw84Vt0XbakvbdxhQWMPfZMcDGldP1BGA=", "project"=>"--- !ruby/object:OpenStruct\r\ntable:\r\n  :id: 3\r\n  :description: ''\r\n  :default_branch: master\r\n  :public: false\r\n  :ssh_url_to_repo: git@git.mydomain.com:mygroup/demoproject.git\r\n  :http_url_to_repo: http://git.mydomain.com/mygroup/demoproject.git\r\n  :web_url: http://git.mydomain.com/mygroup/demoproject\r\n  :owner:\r\n    id: 3\r\n    name: mygroup\r\n    created_at: '2013-05-18T21:05:10Z'\r\n  :name: demoproject\r\n  :name_with_namespace: mygroup / demoproject\r\n  :path: demoproject\r\n  :path_with_namespace: mygroup/demoproject\r\n  :issues_enabled: true\r\n  :merge_requests_enabled: false\r\n  :wall_enabled: false\r\n  :wiki_enabled: true\r\n  :snippets_enabled: false\r\n  :created_at: '2013-05-18T21:05:48Z'\r\n  :last_activity_at: '2014-01-01T14:05:25Z'\r\n  :namespace:\r\n    created_at: '2013-05-18T21:05:10Z'\r\n    description: ''\r\n    id: 3\r\n    name: mygroup\r\n    owner_id: 1\r\n    path: mygroup\r\n    updated_at: '2013-05-18T21:05:10Z'\r\n", "commit"=>"Add"}
Redirected to http://ci.mydomain.com/
Completed 302 Found in 90ms (ActiveRecord: 6.0ms)
```

Any ideas about this?

**Edit:** Hadn't opened my eyes wide enough, just found https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/291 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, CI only supports gitlab 6.3+. I just upgraded to the 6.4-stable branch, which fixed the problem.